# Reactjs SassError: An @import loop has been found

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am creating a project using `Reactjs` as a `frontend library` and i am also using `sass` for styling .I have various sass files in my project .The two main files  are `styles.scss` and `color.scss`.When i am trying to `import color.scss` in one of `scss` file i am facing this issue.I want to use `color.scss` in all my `scss` files

//style.scss

```
// vendors
@import "~bootstrap-scss/bootstrap.scss";
@import "vendors/font-awesome";
@import "vendors/themify";
@import "vendors/feather-icon";
@import "vendors/animate";
@import "vendors/owl.carousel.scss";
@import "vendors/slick.scss";
@import "vendors/slick-theme.scss";
@import "utils/helpers.scss";

//color
@import "./color.scss";
//base
@import "base/typography.scss";
@import "base/reset.scss";

// components
@import "components/buttons";
@import "components/tabs";
@import "components/msg";
@import "components/dropdown";
@import "components/chat-box";
@import "components/tootip";
@import "components/loader";
@import "components/switchery";
@import "components/collapse";
@import "components/call";
@import "components/call-list";
@import "components/according";
@import "components/tour";

//layout
@import "layout/grid.scss";
@import "layout/sidebar.scss";
@import "layout/content.scss";
@import "layout/dark.scss";
@import "layout/rtl.scss";
@import "layout/login";
@import "layout/forms.scss";
@import "layout/customizer.scss";

//pages
@import "pages/inner-pages";
@import "pages/landing";
@import "pages/inner-pages-responsive";
@import "pages/landing-responsive";
@import "pages/landing-page";
@import "pages/react_plugin";

// themes
@import "themes/admin.scss";
@import "themes/theme.scss";
@import "themes/responsive.scss";

// ReactToastify
@import "~react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
@import "~react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

// ToolTip
@import "~react-tippy/dist/tippy.css";

// Image gallery
@import "~react-image-lightbox/style.css";
```

//color.scss

```
@import "utils/variables.scss";
@import "style";
@import "vendors/slick";
@import "vendors/slick-theme";
html {
    &.style1 {
        $primary-color :#3a62b8;
        $primary-light: #f6f7fa;
        $gray1 : #e4e7ef;
        @import "style";
    }
    &.style2 {
        $primary-color :#064c3c;
        $primary-light: #f4faf9;
        $gray1 : #e1f1ee;
        @import "style";
    }
    &.style3 {
        $primary-color :#9b4aff ;
        $primary-light:#faf8fc;
        $gray1: #f4effa;
        @import "style";
    }
    &.style4 {
        $primary-color :#00d3cb;
        $primary-light:#ebfafa;
        $gray1: #daf6f5;
        @import "style";
    }
    &.style5 {
        $primary-color :#ff5b92 ;
        $primary-light:#f8f5f6;
        $gray1 : #faebf0;
        @import "style";
    }
    &.style6 {
        $primary-color :#ff803c ;
        $primary-light:#fff9f5;
        $gray1 : #faeae0;
        @import "style";
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSJAn.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think the reason is really clear. Watch the second line of the `color.scss`. You can find that you are importing `style.scss` there. That might be the reason of the `@import` loop

Comment: sirius: Nowi am not importing `color.scss` in my `style.scss` .But its throwing another error  `SassError: Undefined variable: "$light-color".` This Light is in my other `scss.file`

Comment: First of all, try to restart the project again. Second, try this simple trick. Comment  all the import and enable them one by one. You can find which on.